# Average in Excel excluding cells with dash?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm just trying to get the average but I don't want to count the cells that have a dash in it.  How can I average only the cells with numbers?

ex. of 4 columns:

```
9  1  -  8
-  5  7  9
6  -  3  1
8  3  7  -
```

Answer (score 4):

Dash or hyphen (-) can appear due to two reasons in your data:

i) The data in the cell is 0 (zero) but formatted as accounting number format. Zero is shown as  dash or hyphen in accounting number format.

ii) The cell actually contains dash as text.

In second case, simple average function should work like:

```
=Average(A2:A5)
```

It seems average function didn't work in your case. So, your data probably contains zero as accounting number format, which is shown as hyphen. So, you can use the following formula to average all non-zero numbers :

```
=AVERAGEIF(A2:A5,"<>0")
```

Answer (score 0):

*You can use either of the formulas:*

Write formula in cell A6,

`=AVERAGEIF(A2:A5,"<> -")`

**or**, you can also use this array formula.

```
{=AVERAGE(IF(ISNUMBER(A2:A5),A2:A5))}
```

**N.B.**

- Finish the second formula with Ctrl+Shift+Enter.
- Drag both the formulas right to fill cells, for Average of Column B to D.

Comment: Unable to understand Y this answer has been DOWN VOTED ?